# LaTeX Document cuts off

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning

I created a document with sections and subsections and made it a table of contents. There are about twenty sections. However, after the 9th section, a new page doesn't start, rather it cuts off so I can't see the rest of the document. I added test text, but it still didn't work. Does anyone know why this is? Below is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\title{Notes on SAT Math}
\maketitle


\newpage
\tableofcontents

\newpage
\section{Exponents and Radicals}

\subsection{Laws of Exponents}
Here are some of the important Laws of Exponents: 

\subsection{Evaluating Expressions with Exponents}

\subsection{Solving equations with Exponents}

\subsection{Simplifying Square Roots}


\section{Percent}
\subsection{Percent change}

\subsection{Simple and Compound Interest}

\subsection{Percent Word Problems}

\section{Exponential vs Linear Growth}
\subsection{Linear Growth and Decay}
\subsection{Exponential Growth and Decay}

\section{Proportion}

\section{Rates}
\subsection{Conversion Factors}

\section{Expressions}
\subsection{Combining Like Terms} 
\subsection{Expansion and Factoring}
\subsection{Combining, dividing, and splitting fractions}

\section{More Equation Solving Strategies}
\subsection{Matching coefficients}
\subsection{Clearing denominators}

\section{Systems of Equations}
\subsection{Substitution}
\subsection{Elimination}
\subsection{Systems with no and infinite solutions}
\subsection{Word Problems}
\subsection{More Complex Systems}
\subsection{Graphs of Systems of Equations}

\section{Inequalities}
\subsection{How to Solve Inequalities}
\subsection{Inequality Word Problems}
\subsection{Graphs of Inequalities}

\section{Word Problems}

\section{Lines}
\subsection{Slope and y-intercept}
\subsection{Slope Intercept and Point Slope Form}
\subsection{Finding the intersection of two lines}
\subsection{Parallel and Perpendicular lines}
\subsection{Horizontal and Vertical Lines}

\section{Interpreting Linear Models}

\section{Functions}
\subsection{What is a Function?}
\subsection{When are Functions Undefined?}
\subsection{Finding the intersection of two lines}
\subsection{Parallel and Perpendicular lines}
\subsection{Horizontal and Vertical Lines}

\section{Quadratics}
\subsection{Tactics for Finding the Roots}
\subsection{Completing the Square}
\subsection{Vertex and Vertex Form}
\subsection{Parallel and Perpendicular lines}
\subsection{Parallel and Perpendicular lines}

\section{Synthetic Division}
\subsection{Performing Synthetic Division}
\subsection{Equivalent Expressions}
\subsection{The Remainder Theorem}

\section{Complex Numbers}

\section{Absolute Value}

\section{Angles}
\subsection{Exterior Angle Theorem}
\subsection{Parallel Lines}
\subsection{Polygons}

\section{Triangles}
\subsection{Isosceles and Equilateral Triangles}
\subsection{Right Triangles}
\subsection{Special Right Triangles}
\subsection{Similar Triangles}
\subsection{Radians}

\section{Circles}
\subsection{Area and circumference}
\subsection{Arc Length}
\subsection{Area of a Sector}
\subsection{Central and Inscribed Angles}
\subsection{Equations of Circles}

\section{Trigonometry}
\subsection{Sine, cosine, and tangent}
\subsection{Trigonometric Identities}
\subsection{Evaluating Trigonometric Expressions}

\section{Reading Data}

\section{Probability}

\section{Statistics I}
\subsection{Mean, median, mode}
\subsection{Range and Standard Deviation}
\subsection{Histograms and Dot Plots}
\subsection{Word problems involving averages}

\section{Statistics II}
\subsection{Statistical Sampling}
\subsection{Using and Interpreting Line of Best Fit}
\subsection{Margin of Error}
\subsection{Confidence Intervals}
\subsection{Experimental Design and Conclusions}


\section{Volume}



\end{document}
```

Comment: After you type in contents in between sectioning titles, the page breaks will be normal.

Answer (score 1):

As muzimuzhi Z noted, the problem here is that LaTeX doesn't want to break between section headings that are in close succession. This is normally the desired result since you wouldn't want a page break between, e.g., the headings for a section and a subsection that begins the section.

If you look in your log output, you'll see an `overfull \vbox` warning which is indicating that the content on the final page is extending beyond the normal page vertically.

You can just put some dummy text in each subsection to allow LaTeX to do the page breaks and all will be well.